# zlib build not configuring properly with cross compiler, ignores AR?

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, zlib, configure

I am trying to cross-compile zlib for an ARM processor using crosstool-ng, and its resulting compiler `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`.  I set the `CC` variable to use the cross compiler, as well as `AR` and `RANLIB`, then I run them with `./configure` as follows:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib LDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libz.so.1" ./configure --shared --prefix=/usr
```

The problem is that it spits out a `Makefile` without the `AR` variable I had set, instead it has `AR` set to libtool, which is for my native Mac machine.  Here is what the Makefile has set:

```
AR=libtool
ARFLAGS=-o
RANLIB=ranlib
```

I can manually edit the Makefile and change `AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar` and `ARFLAGS=rcs` which fixes the build.  But that is a hack to me.  Here is the configure script:

http://pastebin.com/trmJbPKb

Does anyone see anything wrong with how I run the configure command?

Comment: are you on os x? another incantation: /.../mingw-w64-i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ar -o libz.a adler32.o crc32.o deflate.o infback.o inffast.o inflate.o inftrees.o trees.o zutil.o compress.o uncompr.o gzclose.o gzlib.o gzread.o gzwrite.o 
/U.../mingw-w64-i686/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ar: no operation specified (possibly because of no uname https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers/issues/10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with `CHOST=arm-linux-gnueabihf` instead of setting `CC`, `AR`, etc.  That will prefix the commands with that string.

Comment: are you suggesting make CHOST=XXX here? Didn't seem to take here [1.2.8] for some reason, though calling them all out did...

Comment: Maybe you need to write a new question.

Comment: @rogerdpack you need to put `CHOST=*` before `.configure`, not after

Comment: In the end seems I cross compiled it like `./configure && make AR=XX CC=XX ... ARFLAGS=rcs` (that was to make it compile for windows) FWIW